# Prevent shell closing with virtualenvwrapper through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, virtualenvwrapper

I'm creating a `.cmd` batch file in Windows 10. In this script I have to create a virtual environment with `virtualenvwrapper` called `Test`. For this, I prepared this script:

```bat
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
mkvirtualenv Test
pause
```

To run it I just double-click the `.cmd` script. The problem is that the command `mkvirtualenv Test` closes the shell before `pause` every time. It seems that the environment creation closes the shell and all other lines are ignored.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Is `mkvirtualenv` a batch file on its own? if yes, put `call` before it...

Comment: I tried to use `call mkvirtualenv Test`. It does its job (in the sense that it create a virtual environment) but after that the shell close again.

Comment: What about `start "" /WAIT mkvirtualenv Test`?